# How do you make a smooth JavaFX LinearGradient over a large surface?

Tags: javafx, linear-gradients

Why does the following code lead to a blocky gradient?  i.e. the gradient is not smooth, you can see some of the rectangles that make it up.

Is there a way to fix this?
BTW I'm running this on Vista, but I've also experienced this on a Mac as well.

```
var stage:Stage = Stage {
title: "Louis' Photo Wall"
width: 900
height: 600

scene: Scene {
    content : Rectangle {
        width:  bind stage.scene.width
        height: bind stage.scene.height
        fill:LinearGradient {
            startX : 0.0
            startY : 0.0
            endX : 0.0
            endY : 1.0
            stops: [
                Stop {
                    color : Color {
                        red:0.0
                        blue:0.0
                        green:0.0
                    }

                    offset: 0.0
                },
                Stop {
                    color : Color {
                        red:0.8
                        blue:0.8
                        green:0.8
                    }
                    offset: 1.0
                },

            ]
        }

    }//OuterRectangle
}
```

}

Comment: I don't see the problem when I run that code under NetBeans 6.5 with Java 1.6.0_11 on a Windows XP system.   The LinearGradient produce is smooth -- not blocky.   Resizing maintains gradient for entire window.  Monitor I'm using is a Samsung 214T (driven at 1600x1200).

Comment: Update, I do see it, but the blocky effect is not dramatic.  See submitted answer.

Comment: When you say blocky, are there solid blocks or is there sort of a wavy effect that is suggestive of blocks?

Comment: Yeah, it looks a bit like the gradient might look if printed on paper.  You're right it is very minor, but it's enough to notice for  black and white at least.  I find it easier to notice if there's three stops, black, white, black, with white being 0.9, 0.9, 0.9.  I tried to take a screenshot of it, but the screenshot came out really bad for some reason

Answer (score 0):

The blocky amount is not dramatic.

Shifting to a endX of 1.0 seems to give a more obvious variation with a diagonalization of the blocky result.

A hypothesis is that a couple of things are going on. 
1.  A r/g/b color is not really continuous, but has 256 steps.  (8 bits).  A 0.8 of 255 is 204.
2.  When one maps from 0 to 0.8 for a color into 600 pixels, one gets an increment per pixel that cannot be completely smooth.  The scene size is actually 792x566 when I make a run.    So the gradient would use  has 566/204 = 2.775 pixels for one color before shifting to the next.  That causes fluctuation where transitions are made.

This doesn't explain why using 0.0 to 1.0 for the stops (instead of 0.0 to 0.8) results (at least in my runs) with what seems to be a smooth transition.

---

Follow-up:   There is an `ofTheWay` method that LinearGradient probably uses for interpolation.  A code example and results...

```
for (v in [0.00..1.00 step 1.0/600]) {
   println("{%7.5f v} {Color.WHITE.ofTheWay(Color.BLACK,v)}");
}
```

which prints

```
0.00000 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=255,green=255,blue=255,opacity=1.0]
0.00167 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=255,green=255,blue=255,opacity=1.0]
0.00333 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=254,green=254,blue=254,opacity=1.0]
0.00500 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=254,green=254,blue=254,opacity=1.0]
0.00667 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=253,green=253,blue=253,opacity=1.0]
0.00833 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=253,green=253,blue=253,opacity=1.0]
0.01000 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=252,green=252,blue=252,opacity=1.0]
0.01167 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=252,green=252,blue=252,opacity=1.0]
0.01333 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=252,green=252,blue=252,opacity=1.0]
0.01500 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=251,green=251,blue=251,opacity=1.0]
0.01667 javafx.scene.paint.Color[red=251,green=251,blue=251,opacity=1.0]
...
```

Comment: Examination of the actual colors present (from the viewpoint of JavaFX) on the gradient shows 2 to 5 occurrences of each specific color level.  So the bands present are 2 pixels to 5 pixels high for the stage height in use.